Solving list manipulation exercise involving longest sequence of identical digits in a list using functional programming idiom
I have been trying to improve my list manipulation skills by doing some of the exercises in Wolfram's Intro book. I am struggling to solve this question using only functional programming constructs. https://lab.wolframcloud.com/env/f3d2c9ae-e429-47dd-ad81-0b9723ebc3f5#sidebar=eiwl/30-rearranging-lists
The question is: 30.8

Find the lengths of the longest sequences of identical digits in 2^n for n up to 100.

The heart of the solution will be something like this:
longestSequence[digits_List, length_Integer] := Cases[Partition[digits, length, 1], {Repeated[x_, {length}]}]
I hoped to be able to use a function like NestWhileList[] while trying progressively
longer values of the length argument. I can make it work by using a Range[] that is big
enough to exceed the largest partition size that seems possible, but that is too hacky.
If length is too large, it will return {}, and it should be possible to use that in
the while condition. I would appreciate any guidance in finding a clean functional programming solution.

First get the digits of 2^n in a list, then split it into runs of identical digits. Finally get the lengths of the runs and take the max:
Max[Length /@ Split[IntegerDigits@#]] & /@ (2^Range[100])

{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, \
3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, \
2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}


That is a beautiful, concise solution! I'm sure that's the best solution possible for this problem. The lesson for me is that I really need to understand ALL the list-handling functions. My ignorance of the capabilities of Split obviates the use of any of the fancy code I was trying to use (NestWhileList, for example). Accepting this as the solution.
